# MVC 3 RAZOR coding logic is rendering as text even they are within @{ }

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

What is wrong with following line of codes?

```
 <table>
        @{
            string subGroup = "";

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                if (item.SubGroupName != subGroup)
                {
                    subGroup = item.SubGroupName;
            <tr style="background-color: #C1E0FF; text-align: left">
                <td colspan="2">
                    @item.SubGroupName;
                </td>
            </tr>
                }
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.configurationitemkey)
                </td>
            <td>
                if (item.IsBoolean)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsAvailable)
                else
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ConfigurationItemValue)
            </td>

            </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
```

Following code lines render as test even they are within @{ }

```
<td>
    if (item.IsBoolean)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsAvailable)
    else
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ConfigurationItemValue)
</td>
```

Guide me best way of implementing this type of programming logic in MVC RAZOR

Thanks

@Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting an `@` before them, because the tag before them is `<td>` meaning that the Razor parser has switched back to HTML context and not server side code:

```
@{
    string subGroup = "";
}

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.SubGroupName != subGroup)
        {
            subGroup = item.SubGroupName;
        }
        <tr style="background-color: #C1E0FF; text-align: left">
            <td colspan="2">
                @item.SubGroupName;
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.configurationitemkey)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.IsBoolean)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsAvailable)
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ConfigurationItemValue)
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Remark: in the example you have shown you don't seem to be using the `subGroup` variable anywhere in the code, but I am including it anyway as probably that's only a simplified version of your real code and you might need it.

Comment: thanks. ya i tried but putting @before if results rendering a blank page

Comment: ok. i'll try now. by the way i have used subGroup variable in if (item.SubGroupName != subGroup)
        {
            subGroup = item.SubGroupName;
        }

Comment: Thanks, i has worked. But now [if (item.SubGroupName != subGroup)
        {
            subGroup = item.SubGroupName;
        }] is not working. Actually i dont want repeat same subgroup.

Comment: Done. Thanks. This time i forgot to put  @item.SubGroupName within if condition>>>